# resetting points of an already plotted scatter in matplotlib

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scipy

if I have a scatter plot in matplotlib that returns a CircleCollection:

`coll = plt.scatter(rand(5), rand(5), c="k")`

how can I reset the colors of just specific points? I notice that `coll` is not iterable. I want to just alter the face/edge colors of already plotted points, although they already have a color set from the initial `plt.scatter` call. How can this be done?

For example: just change the color of the second point plotted, e.g.:

`coll[1].set_color("r") # this does not work, coll not indexable this way`

I know I can pass a vector of colors to `c=` in `scatter` but I'd like to intentionally reset the points later, since the colors are not known for all the points at the time when `plt.scatter` is initially called.

*edit*: further explanation. I am looking for the simplest way to color points in a scatter based on different conditions. if `points` is a two-d array and you plot it with `scatter(points[:, 0], points[:, 1], c-"k")`, it's convenient to later on based on certain conditions, e.g.

```
# replot certain points in red with alpha
selected = points[:, 0] > 0.5
plt.scatter(selected[:, 0], selected[:, 1], c="r", alpha=0.5)
```

here I replot over the old points but this is messy since the new points are plotted with an alpha, so it will not give the desired effect. The various conditions according to which points have to be re-colored might be complex and happen later than when the initial scatter is made, so it's convenient to just be able to change the color of an existing point, rather than split the points up based on conditions and plot them all separately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works for me.  Probably you need to call `plt.draw` before (or instead of) `fig.show`.

```
coll = plt.scatter(rand(5), rand(5), c="k")
fig = plt.gcf()
fig.show()  # or fig.savefig("a.png")

coll.set_color(['b', 'g', 'r', 'y', 'k'])
fig.show()  # or fig.savefig("b.png")
```

**Updated**

This is how to partially modify colors.  You need to extend `colors` array explicitly if you use the single color when calling `scatter`.

```
num = 5
coll = plt.scatter(rand(num), rand(num), c='k')
# coll = plt.scatter(rand(num), rand(num), c=['b', 'g', 'r', 'y', 'k'])
fig = plt.gcf()
fig.show()

colors = coll.get_facecolor()
if colors.shape[0] == 1:
    newcolors = np.tile(colors, (num, 1))
else:
    newcolors = colors
newcolors[0] = [0, 0.75, 0.75, 1]
coll.set_color(newcolors)
```

Comment: Why doesn't it work to first get the color vector of the points and then set it, as in: `colors = coll.get_facecolors()[0]` then modify `colors` and pass it to `set_color`?

Comment: I updated the answer.  Read the document of `plt.scatter` to see how the argument of `set_color` is treated depending on its shape.

Answer (score 2):

When you call `scatter`, pass every point a color, then you can change the `_facecolors` ndarray directly.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.collections import PathCollection
from numpy.random import rand
x = rand(5)
y = rand(5)
coll = plt.scatter(x, y, c=["k"]*len(x)) # must set color for every point
coll._facecolors[2,:] = (1, 0, 0, 1)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use separate lists:

```
plt.scatter(x1, y1, c='b')
plt.scatter(x2, y2, c='k')
```

Look at [this](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.scatter).

You can also have a list in c of the same length as the x and y.

Comment: is there no way to do this without separate lists? I don't necessarily know at the time of plotting all the points which ones will be colored

Comment: You can use a list for c instead of a letter and change these one by one before you redo the graph.

Comment: right, but that means I have to do all the computations of the colors before the initial call to scatter is made, no?

Comment: You can redo the graph after the group of changes. I haven't tried to replot a point with a different color.